# RKHS inclusion relationship of the Erf network's NTK

Tags: neural-networks, kernel-trick

In the referenced [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.10683), it is stated that for ReLU networks, the Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Space (RKHS) of the Neural Tangent Kernels (NTK) remains unchanged regardless of the model's depth. I am curious to know if, when considering the Erf (error function) as an activation function, the RKHS inclusion relationship remains the same as that of ReLU networks.